# codeName: 'AtlasError', connectionGeneration: 0, [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' } }

Tags: database, mongodb

codeName: 'AtlasError',
connectionGeneration: 0,
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' }
}

By just changing admin user password it worked fine for me

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I used incorrect password in the connection URL.

MongoDB connection URL should look like this:

```
"mongodb+srv://name:< password >@clusterName.rlzlo.mongodb.net/DatabaseName?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

So check if you had provided the correct password or not